# How to unzip a column in a Spark DataFrame using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gzip

I have parquet files with a column containing gzipped content.
Currently my Spark (written in Scala) Job uses the `Java.io Reader` chain to stringify the content:

```
val output: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder
val byteArrayInputStream: ByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(x)
try {
  val gzipInputStream: GZIPInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)
  try {
    val inputStreamReader: InputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    try {
      val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
      try {
        var line: String = null
        do {
          line = bufferedReader.readLine()
          if (line != null)
            output.append(line)
        } while (line != null)

      } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
          bufferedReader.close()
        }
      }
    }
    finally {
      if (inputStreamReader != null) {
        inputStreamReader.close()
      }
    }
  }
  finally {
    if (gzipInputStream != null) {
      gzipInputStream.close()
    }
  }
}
finally {
  if (byteArrayInputStream != null) {
    byteArrayInputStream.close()
  }
}
val out = output.toString
return out
```

But this leads to an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` Exception in the Hadoop Cluster.

Are there better performing methods for unzipping the content?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a spark UDF (User Defined function) that decompresses gzip byte array:

1. define a UDF that gets byte array and return a String

```java
    static UDF1 unzip = (UDF1<byte[], String>) YourClass::gzipDecompress;
```

2. register that UDF

```java
    spark.sqlContext().udf().register("unzip", unzip, DataTypes.StringType);
```

3. ask spark to calculate a column using the UDF

```java
    df.withColumn("unzipped_column", callUDF("unzip", col("your_original_column_with_gzip_data")))
```

you may benefit from taking a look at other similar gzip decompression implementation in scala, ignoring failures it would be:

```scala
def decompress(compressed: Array[Byte]): String = {
    val inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed))
    scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString
}
```

source: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/scalatra-example/src/main/scala/io/restassured/scalatra/support/Gzip.scala

Note: the UDF example is written in java but should be **very** similar in scala, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#callUDF-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've still the same problem with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` on the Hadoop cluster. Do you know another methods to unzip a Byte-Array without the nested Java Readers? Thanks for your anwer

Comment: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream when trying to use GZIPInputStream in UDF

Comment: Ivan please take a look here https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/scalatra-example/src/main/scala/io/restassured/scalatra/support/Gzip.scala